# Javascript to count number of nested divs with content

Tags: javascript, html, count

I have a main div which contains many other divs, some of which have content.

```
<div id="mainHolder">
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_0">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_1">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_2">
       XXXXXXX
   </div>
<!--continues to 24-->
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_23">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_24">
      YYYYYYYY
   </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking to count how many of the nested divs with the 'class' 'cellHolder' contain html text (ie not empty)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- query necessary elements
- filter out non-empty (non-spaces-only
  `textContent`) cells
- get `length`

```js
const nonEmptyCellsCount = [...document.querySelectorAll('#mainHolder .cellHolder')]
   .filter(cell => 
      cell
        .textContent
        .replace(/\s/g, ''))
   .length
   
console.log(nonEmptyCellsCount)
```

```html
<div id="mainHolder">
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_0">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_1">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_2">
       XXXXXXX
   </div>
<!--continues to 24-->
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_23">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_24">
      YYYYYYYY
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop to select empty divs (use innerText to select only visible characters):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder").length; i++) {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].innerText.length > 0) {
    console.log("Div with id " + document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].id + " is NOT empty. (It has length " + document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].innerText.length + ")");
  } else {
    console.log("Div with id " + document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].id + " is empty. (It has length " + document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].innerText.length + ")");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainHolder">
  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_0">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_1">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_2">
    XXXXXXX
  </div>
  <!--continues to 24-->
  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_23">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_24">
    YYYYYYYY
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can easily make a counter:

```js
var emptyDivs = 0;
var nonEmptyDivs = 0;
// Delcaring variables

for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder").length; i++) {
  // For loop which checks every element
  
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("cellHolder")[i].innerText.length > 0) { // If length of innerText of selected div is higher than 0
  
    // TRUE -  Div is not empty
    nonEmptyDivs++;

  } else {
  
    // FALSE - Div is empty
    emptyDivs++;

  }
}

// Log result to console
console.log("There are " + emptyDivs + " empty divs and " + nonEmptyDivs + " non-empty divs")
```

```html
<div id="mainHolder">
  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_0">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_1">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_2">
    XXXXXXX
  </div>
  <!--continues to 24-->
  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_23">
  </div>

  <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_24">
    YYYYYYYY
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("DIV")` will return ***all*** `<div>`'s (even outside target div with `mainHolder` id)

Comment: Oh, it is true. Thank your very much! I have updated my answer

Comment: [reading `innerText` may trigger reflows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext), which may be considered negative side-effect from performance standpoint

Answer (score -1):

`.filter` to the rescue:

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll("div.cellHolder");
let length = Object.values(a).filter((x => x.innerText !== "")).length;
console.log(length);
```

```html
<div id="mainHolder">
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_0">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_1">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_2">
       XXXXXXX
   </div>
<!--continues to 24-->
   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_23">
   </div>

   <div class="cellHolder" id="d1_24">
      YYYYYYYY
   </div>
</div>
```